# How to convert Ruby protobuf Message to JSON while preserving the case used in the proto?

Tags: ruby, protocol-buffers

When you convert a Protobuf Message in Ruby to JSON using `to_json` it converts all fieldnames to camelCase.

e.g. with protobuf message Person as

```
message Person {
  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;
  string email_address = 3;
```

and Person in Ruby as

```
person = Person.new(:name => "Bob",
                        :id => 1,
                        :email_address => "foo@bar.com")
```

Serialized to JSON

```
person.to_json
>>> {"name":"Bob","id":"1","emailAddress":"foo@bar.com"}
```

the field `email_address` gets serialized in camelCase instead of snake case as it is in the proto

How can you serialize it with the original proto fieldnames?

I tried converting it to a Ruby `Hash` (with `.to_h`) at first since it preserves field names, but ran into a different issue. Fields with `double` values will be rendered as a `Hash` like `price: {"value": 10.0"}` instead of `price: 10.0`.

Answer (score 3):

Buried deep in the [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/protobuf/+/HEAD/ruby/ext/google/protobuf_c/message.c#1044) is the answer.

There is an option in `to_json` to preserve the case used in the proto by passing in `preserve_proto_fieldnames: true`

e.g. `person.to_json({preserve_proto_fieldnames: true})`

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be elsewhere in the Ruby protobuf documentation